# Displaying Date and Time in Codesys

Tags: codesys

I am trying to display system time in Codesys Visualization.
I am using "#dt" to get the time and displaying it in Text field using

> %t[ddd MMM dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss] place holder.

I want to get display the local time. But I am getting in 'UTC' time stander.

What I should do to get the local time?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if the `#dt` is really necessary. I just typed the expression `%t[ddd MMM dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss]` in the Text field of a rectangle object and it displays your PC's local time.

Answer (score 0):

CodeSYS2 %t%a %b %d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).